# PHP Powershell command

Tags: php, powershell

Trying to run the following command in php to run powershell command...

the following works:

```
$output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('powershell get-service | group-object'));
```

I can not run it like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('powershell get-service | group-object');
```

it will not pass the pipe | character

but if I try to run:

```
$output = shell_exec(escapeshellcmd('powershell get-service | where-object {$_.status -eq "Running"}'));
```

I get no output.

The following:

```
$cmd = escapeshellcmd('powershell get-service | where-object {$_.status -eq "Running"}');
```

returns:

```
powershell get-service ^| where-object ^{^$_.status -eq ^"Running^"^}
```

Any suggestions on why this is happening  and how to fix this?

Edit: Also I could run it as .ps1 script but I want to be able to pass $var to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll take a stab although I have no PHP experience whatsoever.

I have a feeling that what's happening is your pipe character is being interpreted by the command shell instead of PowerShell. For example if you ran the following at the cmd.exe command prompt:

```
dir /s | more
```

The output of the first command gets piped to the input of the second just like you'd expect in PowerShell.

Escaping the string will only make the problem worse because you're transforming the string in such a way that PowerShell has no idea how to unescape it.

Try enclosing your original PowerShell expression in a quote like the following:

```
$output = shell_exec('powershell.exe -c "get-service | group-object"');
```

Or preferably, it looks like there's an [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)() function that does not go through the command shell. This might work better.

```
$output = exec('powershell.exe -c get-service | group-object');
```

Comment: shell_exec('powershell -c "get-service | where-object {$_.status -eq \"Running\"}');

worked like a charm Josh, Thanks!

Comment: Give the exec command a shot too. Since you're calling PowerShell directly there's no real need to go through the command shell first. It also may avoid issues with other characters such as percent symbols.

Answer (score 2):

```
'powershell get-service | group-object'
```

will be interpreted as

1. run powershell and pass it get-service as an argument
2. then pipe the output of *powershell* to group_object (i.e. not the output of get-service)

What you want is for powershell to see `get-service | group-object` as it's argument, so you have to enclose that in quotes, like this.

```
 $output = shell_exec('powershell "get-service | group-object"');
```