# PHP powershell cmdlet issue with pipe symbol and variables

Tags: php, powershell, pipe, shell-exec, powershell-cmdlet

I looked for an answer to this question and found this article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353551/php-powershell-command)

However, I can not get the suggested to work when inserting some php variables, the command I am passing is:

```
 $command = "powershell -command get-aduser -Filter {(givenname -Like '*".$username[0]."*') -And (surname -Like '*".$username[1]."*')} -Properties samaccountname | format-table samaccountname 2>&1";
```

And I get error
string ''format-table' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
' (length=101)

How do I get this to work so that it uses the variables AND lets me pipe it to a table?

Answer (score 3):

To test this out you should just paste that command into a windows command prompt.

The pipe `|` is being interpreted by the command parser before it even gets to powershell, so whatever is after the pipe is treated as a separate executable or command to be run.

You could try to quote the whole command string, but then you might also have to go through pains to escape any embedded double quotes `"`.

But the simplest thing right off the bat might be to just escape the pipe. The escape character for the windows command prompt is caret `^`:

```
$command = "powershell -command get-aduser -Filter {(givenname -Like '*".$username[0]."*') -And (surname -Like '*".$username[1]."*')} -Properties samaccountname ^| format-table samaccountname 2>&1";
```

Comment: That fixed it! thanks so much, I've been messing with it all morning.